# sencha touch rest failure

Tags: node.js, error-handling, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on a sencha touch app, which communicates via rest with a nodejs server, which communicates with a mysql db.

When I try to add a duplicate entry:

```
connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err.message);
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.json(err);
            return;
        } [...]
```

the db returns an error "ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'aaa12345678a' for key 'OfferNo'".
If this happens my nodejs should respond to the sencha touch app.
At the moment it returns via json:

`{
  "code": "ER_DUP_ENTRY",
  "index": 0
}`

(Why is the message missing?)
But this isn't the problem. In my app I try to use the respond, to display an error message:

```
currentProductBacklog.save({
            failure: function(response, opt){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.responseText);
            },[...]
```

Now I get the alert, but with no text. When I debug and look what is contained in response, it contains the object, which should have been saved, but no error message, beside the error 400 somewhere.
I don't know if my server needs to send the respond in a special format, or if I'm doing something wrong on the client side.
Any suggestions would be nice!

Comment: *Didn't realise this was 6 months old...* Can you check if the `err` in your `connection.query` is an instance of some kind of exception? Not sure if you can pass exceptions around, you'll get header information from the response undoubtedly.

Alternatively have you tried creating a new object with differently named fields in it to solve this?